# Name of symmetric multilinear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, terminology, multilinear-algebra

What's the name (if any) for the multilinear symmetric function that maps a square matrix over some commutative ring $R$ with $1$ to a value in $R$?  It's basically like the determinant, but symmetric.  It's normalized such that the unit matrix maps to the $1 \in R$.

For example, a $3 \times 3$ matrix would map as follows

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i \\
\end{pmatrix} \mapsto aei + bfg + cdh + ceg + bdi + afh $$

Comment: This is the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)).

Comment: ah, thanks! If you write is as an answer I can mark is as solution.

Comment: Please define "quadratic matrix"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_matrix